# building time environment variable for Framework search path

Tags: macos, gcc, frameworks, build

On mac os x, I'm trying to link against frameworks that are in a non standard location.
Is there any environment variable as LIBRARY_PATH but for frameworks to tell the compilers to look before at the Libraries located into a certain directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH is what you want.